# Can a recommendation system be built without any user ratings?

Tags: recommender-system

I was planning to make an artwork recommendation system as a project by using the WikiArt open source dataset available on kaggle, I'm still looking for datasets which might already have user ratings but is it possible to make a recommender without any user ratings? The dataset currently has these features. Any help or insight is appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: yes. You can recommend by similar artist, genre, or style; add in more data like subject matter and your recommendation engine gets even better

Comment: Will you ever get user ratings or feedback in any way? If so, this is the cold start problem which is a common hurdle for recommendation systems. If not, you will probably not be able to get good results by looking at the art info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue for recommender system refered to as **cold start**. You can look it up there are some solutions suggested out there but I have never tested them out. Have a look at this paper:

http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mvolkovs/nips2017_deepcf.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can recommend item similar to the item user selected without having users profiles. The similarity is based on items attributes and the approach often called **More Like This**. MLT is one of the variants of Content-Based Filtering.

See for instance:

- ["Evaluating Item-Item Similarity Algorithms for Movies"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2851581.2892362)
- ["Finding Similar Movies: Dataset, Tools, and Methods"](https://otik.uk.zcu.cz/bitstream/11025/34663/1/Leng.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clarify what kind of recommendation you want to make.

The reason for the rating is to be able to associate an item to a user preference. You can avoid a rating and design the recommendation as a classification problem where you classify a product to some event (someone would like the artwork or not), but this still needs you to design a label based on some information.

In summary yes you can do without a rating but you still need some information on user preference or whatever the label will be.

Comment: I'm a noob, please bear with me. I was wondering what kind of recommendation can be made, since there is no user data, so user based collaborative filtering is out of charts, so is item-based collaborative filtering possible? if yes, then what should I take into consideration? Or is a content based recommendation possible as far as artworks are concerned? Because what I want is like when I want to get recomm for Starry Night, I get other works of Gogh or some other work of similar art style or movement. But I guess I can't get a recommendation on basis of popularity because no user data.

Comment: @Kartikay Sorry, but I disagree with this answer and have downvoted it. This answer only scratches the surface of recommender systems and shouldn't be relied on. Please see the answer I provided.

Comment: I really dont undesrstand why someone downgrades a correct answer just because he doesnt like it. Ofcourse it only scratches the surface since the question is vague. Your answer is also just scratches the surface and its incomplete.

BTW my answer would have been a comment if I had the option.

Comment: It's fine lol, it was a vague question, his answer did help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are two types of recommender systems. One is **community-based**, the other is **content-based**.

In **community-based**, you are effectively telling a user, "you are a young female, here is content that other young females enjoyed".

In **content-based**, you are effectively telling a user, "you liked content A, here is content B that was liked by people who also enjoyed content A".

So, in your case, you would be looking to build a content-based system. That means that you will have to build a meta-data set based on user actions throughout your site. When someone watched content A, what did they watch after that? And then after that? What content made them leave? What content made them sign up for your site or buy something or do some other action on your site? What categories of content are likely to be watched together?

When you can gather that type of metadata then you will be in a better position to create a model. Note that I believe that you can extract this from the sample data you posted, it's just a matter of how you organize it.

Comment: But I don't have any user data to build a meta-data set, If I were to just use this dataset(what I have currently), any tips on how to organize it?